# Modify a table of sqlite database using python

Tags: python, regex, sqlite

I have a sqlite database, let's say test.db. It is the database of my blog, where all the blog contents are stored. Now, it has a table called "posts". "posts" contains all the contents that I have written in my blog. There is a javascript which is present multiple times in the "posts", that I want to replace with something else. So, the concept is to fetch table "posts" and then use regex to select all the similar and then replace it with new one. I fetched the data from "posts" by using a python script. I want help to select using regex and then replace. Below is my code :-

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('/home/bootx/Downloads/test.db')
cur = conn.cursor()

def get_posts():
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM posts")
    print(cur.fetchall())

get_posts()
conn.commit()
conn.close()
print "Connected fetched"
```

Comment: your select print your posts? or what is problem?

Comment: Yeah, no problem. It is actually printing whole table at once. I want to print a column first from the table "posts", let's say the column name is "html". In the column "html", I want to use regex to select a script and all of it's identical then want to replace with a new one.

Comment: As, I can use cur.execute("SELECT html FROM posts") to fetch column html. But, I don't know how to use regex their to select something identical.

Comment: identical rows or columns???

Comment: There are bunch of data within the column "html" and a javascript is there multiple times, I want to select that by using regex.

Comment: can you post how looks like this data?

Comment: Hi, please look at the column "html". Now each data with this column have an identical code. http://s14.postimg.org/cp0mgcm4h/Screenshot_from_2016_03_10_15_15_32.png